# Getting closer to $k$ min-entropy using summation

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

A distribution $D$ over $\Lambda$ has $k$ min-entropy if the largest probability mass given to any element in $\Lambda$ is $2^{-k}$ (i.e., for all $a\in\Lambda$, $D(a)\leq 2^{-k}$, and for some $a$ it is $2^{-k}$). We denote it by $H_\infty(D)=k$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent distributions over $\{0, 1\}^n$ such that both $X$ is $\epsilon$-close in statistical distance to a distribution with $k$ min-entropy and $Y$ is $\epsilon$-close in statistical distance to a distribution with $k$ min-entropy.

Let $Z=X+Y$  denote the distribution over $\{0, 1\}^n$ obtained by sampling $x\sim X$ and $y\sim Y$ and outputting $x+y$, where the sum is addition modulo $2$ coordinate wise.

**Prove** that $Z$ is $\epsilon^2$-close in statistical distance to a distribution with min-entropy **at least** $k$.

It is clear that $H_\infty(Z)\leq\min\{H_\infty(X),H_\infty(Y)\}$, but I don't see how that helps.

Note that by statistical distance I mean TV distance.

Comment: Just to be sure, by statistical distance you mean total variation, yes? 

In any case, this can't be true at the level of generality of your formulation - suppose $X ,Y$ are uniform. It is easy to see that $Z$ is also uniform. So $Z$ cannot get *closer* to any other distribution than $X$ and $Y$. In particular, if I pick $\epsilon$ to be the minimum TV distance that a distribution with min-entropy $k$ is from the uniform, then $Z$ is also at a distance $\ge \epsilon$ from every $k$ min-entropy distribution. Are there missing hypotheses?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I have edited it. Indeed by the statistical distance I mean TV distance. Also I have changed the claim to be proven.

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever find an answer to this? If yes, would you mind giving me a high-level overview of the argument?